# Railsでbundle install 時にエラーが発生する。 Gem::InstallError: listen requires Ruby version >= 2.2.3, ~> 2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

Railsでbundle install 時に下記エラーが出るようになりました。
Rubyのバージョンが関係していると思うのですが、解決策が分からず困っております。
解決策が分かる方教えて頂きたいです。
何卒宜しくお願い致します。

**Gemfile**
ruby '2.1.5'

**エラー文**
Gem::InstallError: listen requires Ruby version >= 2.2.3, ~> 2.2.
An error occurred while installing listen (3.1.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install listen -v '3.1.3'` succeeds before bundling.

Comment: マルチポスト https://teratail.com/questions/34386

Comment: 解決できたなら承認という機能を使用していただけると助かります。

Comment: 承知しました。コメントありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

listenのGithubの[README](https://github.com/guard/listen/blob/v3.1.3/README.md)によるとruby2.1のサポートをやめたのでruby2.2以上にアップデートしてくださいと記載があります。Gemfileを見る限りご利用のrubyのバージョンは2.1.5のようですから2.2以上にアップデートすれば利用できると思います。

Comment: コメント頂きありがとうございます！
Rubyのバージョン(2.1.5→2.3.0)をアップしたことにより解決することができました。